# Child/Parent structure with different classes in C++

Tags: c++

I've decided to make my next game using my own simple engine. I've already written some code for object rendering, physics etc. and now I'm thinking about how to easily connect them together.

I want to make hierarchic structure with one master object, lets call it Scene which will have parent as Sprites or InteractiveObjects and every Sprite or InteractiveObject could have its own child which would have its own child.. I think you already got my point here :)

Let's assume, that every object type will inherit from some base object, let's call it Node for example. I'm not sure yet, if Node will be "real" object which will have its size, position etc. or only abstract wrapper for every object in game (I tend to option two actually).

And finally. My goal is, to have object of actual Scene, call something like Scene->Move(x,y) and it will move every child of Scene (or Sprite, InteractiveObject etc.). Or Scene->Render() and it will render every (renderable) child. If I create Sprite, I want to add child like Sprite->addChild() and child could be another Sprite, InteractiveObject or just simple Node.

And now my question. What's the best way to implement it with C++? Or am I totally wrong and this structure is stupid? :)

Comment: Not stupid at all, it looks like the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I should think that whether or not the structure is sensible depends somewhat on what you really want to achieve -- the system sounds very flexible, but usually there's a trade-off between flexibility and performance. Depending on the genre of the game, performance may be hard enough to come by.

Also, if all things derive from some BaseNode, they all need (although possibly empty) methods for all kinds of things whether or not they actually can be rendered, moved etc. Or you'd end up with lots of dynamic_casts, which isn't very nice either. It might therefore be better to have slightly less flexibility and differentiate between game entities and graphical entities, with the latter being part of the former (you might want to allow a game entity to be made up from multiple graphical entities, or sub-entities, though).

If you do go with your current architecture, I should think that each BaseObject has something like a vector and when you call, say, render() on a master object, it goes through all it's children and calls render on them. They do the same and do any render code that is appropriate to them.

Another question is, though, whether an object could feasibly be attached to several other objects (if there is a difference between rendering and physics, for example). If so, it can get hairy to know when to delete an object, unless you don't use plain BaseObject*, but some form of auto_ptr or shared_ptr.

I hope that this answer does help you a little, though I realise it's not a simple "this is they way!" one.

Comment: It's OK. I had similar idea about how to work with BaseNode but wanted to hear it from someone else. And my queston doesn't have simple "this is the way" answer I think.